# WSO2 API Manager 2.1 on Windows 2012 sign-in issue

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, windows-server-2012-r2, owasp

I am having a problem with the latest out-of-the-box APIM 2.1 running on Microsoft Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard.

If I try to login to the carbon console I get a 
     "Error 403 - Forbidden" on page https://server-url:9443/carbon/admin/login_action.jsp.

Console output is:

```
 WARN - JavaLogger potential cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attack thwarted (user:<anonymous>, ip:10.20.30.40, method:POST, uri:/carbon/admin/login_action.jsp, error:required token is missing from the request)
```

Chrome network console shows:

```
login.jsp:43 GET https://server-url:9443/carbon/admin/js/csrfPrevention.js net::ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED
```

username and password are correct. I can login into the publisher and store.

As a workaround I disable the POST verification in the Owasp.CsrfGuard.Carbon.properties and login to the carbon console works.

Any ideas what can cause the problem and how to really correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known issue with JDK 1.8.0_151](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8189789). (Fixed in JDK 1.8.0_162ea)

Please use JDK 1.8.0_144 instead.

Comment: Downgrading the JDK 8u151 to 8u141 fixed the issue